# Redmine email configuration on Ubuntu 14.04 with gmail

Tags: email, ubuntu, redmine

I have an pre-installed Redmine on Digital Ocean, but the email for the application was not setup yet.

How can I configure the email with gmail smtp settings in Redmine?
The configuration file is: /srv/redmine/config/configuration.yml

I can send mail from console via SSH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I have found the solution.

1. Log in your droplet via ssh from Putty (or other ssh tool).
   1a. ) install sendmail: `sudo apt-get install sendmail`
2. cd the following directory: **`/srv/redmine/config/`**
3. create an you file and called it configuration.yml: **`configuration.yml`**

   nano -w configuration.yml
4. paste the following config:

production:
      email_delivery:
        delivery_method: :async_sendmail
        smtp_settings:
          enable_starttls_auto: true
          address: "smtp.gmail.com" 
          port: '587'
          domain: "smtp.gmail.com" 
          authentication: :plain
          user_name: "your_email@gmail.com" 
          password: "your_password"

5. save this file: CTRL + X + S + Y
6. cd the following directory: /srv/redmine/tmp
7. create an new blank file an named it: restart.txt
8. restart the application: touch /srv/redmine/tmp/restart.txt

and voila, you can send notification mail from redmine :)